# Convert CSV to nested object back to CSV based off previous and need data in PowerShell

Tags: json, xml, powershell, csv

First off, that title may be a little confusing, and not sure how to word it. Please edit it if you need to.

I am tasked with getting logs from a printer, and creating a cumulative report. The printer does not have the ability to supply date ranges, so I need to factor that in. My approach is to take the CSV, and then convert it to a nested object (XML or JSON), so each user can have it's printer's properties. Then I need to turn it back to a CSV and have the different months. If a CSV could not work, maybe I can use a XML, which I could leverage in PowerShell and create some custom report in HTML.

For example, this is what one month would look like

```
PrinterLog-Sep10.csv

User Name  Dept. ID Color Total Black & White Total Total Prints
---------  -------- ----------- ------------------- ------------
Mary Smith 1002     3           3                   6           
Kevin Hart 1006     3           2                   5           
Jeff Davis 1004     4           0                   4           
John Doe   1001     0           0                   0           
Joe Dirt   1003     0           0                   0           
Jane Jones 1005     0           0                   0
```

I also need to factor in that additional users may be added at anytime. So the following month could be like this

```
PrinterLog-Oct19.csv

User Name  Dept. ID Color Total Black & White Total Total Prints
---------  -------- ----------- ------------------- ------------
John Doe   1001     2           5                   8           
Joe Dirt   1003     7           15                  8           
Jeff Davis 1004     6           4                   7           
Mary Smith 1002     6           7                   5           
Will Smart 1007     32          12                  43          
Jane Jones 1005     3           14                  2           
Kevin Hart 1006     6           7                   10
```

My approach has been using this `foreach` loop, but I cannot think of how to check for news, and keep the existing data.

```
foreach ($user in $canonCSV) {
    $final += @{
            $user.'User Name' = @{ 
            "B&W"   = $user.'Black & White Total'
            "Color" = $user.'Color Total'
            "Total" = $user.'Total Prints'
            "Dept" = $user.'Dept. ID'
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe exporting the nested objects into a XML or JSON, but when I import it, not sure how to flatten it to a CSV. I tried using `Compare-Object` but that is not working correctly for additional users. I'm literally losing sleep over this, as I cannot think of a way to get this right. I'm sure it is something small or trivial, but everything is slipping my mind. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you are running sums on data files, consider a data analytics tool (i.e., open-source Python pandas, R, Julia) to loop through files and aggregate by user name. Even consider a database (SQLite, MS Access) to import all csvs and query in SQL. Even Excel with `SUMIFs`.

Comment: Like @Parfait suggested, you might want to consider adding another purpose-built tool into the mix here.  The easiest I would think would be to use excel; you can create an excel object, and open an existing file. Each month could be its own sheet, and then you just need a summary sheet to do all the calculations; from there you can export the summary sheet to csv.  All of this can be done in powershell - you would only ever need to open the excel file to setup/modify the calculations /summary sheet; everything else can be done using and excel object.

Comment: @RepeatDaily Do you think you can point me in the right direction for this? I don't much about Excel, and it looks like there is some VBS scripting that is needed. I can picture it in my mind what you are saying. However, not sure how the summary sheet would be able to add the additional columns.

Comment: VBScript and PowerShell both use the COM interface that Excel exposes. What you can do in one you can do in the other as well. There's no need for switching to VBScript when you're already using PowerShell.

Comment: @Herc08
`$xl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'` to create the application object. `$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open('your workbook.xlsx')` to create the workbook object.  from there you should be able to manipulate all the sheets and their data. It takes a bit of futzing-around with, but it's pretty straightforward if not a bit antiquated. There may be some existing powershell modules out there for this sort of thing too. ^[1] You can do this 100% in powershell. ^[2] You need to have excel installed.